Do you know if this theorem has a name?
I'd like to ask if the following theorem has a name.
Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold, $\mathcal{P}$ a family of open subsets of $M$ satisfying the following:
$(1)$ $\emptyset \in \mathcal{P}$,
$(2)$ if $U,V$ and $U \cap V$ are in $\mathcal{P}$, so is $U \cup V$,
$(3)$ if $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ is a numerable family of disjoint elements in $\mathcal{P}$, then $\coprod_{\alpha} U_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{P}$,
$(4)$ if $U$ is an open subset of $M$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $U \in \mathcal{P}$.
Then $M \in \mathcal{P}$.

I doubt it has a name. These sorts of basic topological lemmas rarely do. Also, why's property (1) relevant, out of curiosity? Apart from the fact that it follows from (3) applied to the empty family, do you really need the empty set for anything?

That's something I was wondering too, I'd need to see the proof though.

If you don't know of a proof then where is this from? Is this an exercise somewhere? If you are only conjecturing this, please don't call it a theorem!

Oh no it's from a book I'm studying, though it's in italian so I don't know of how much help it could be. I was just saying I have to read the proof yet. Anyway the book I'm using is Geometria Differenziale by Marco Abate and Francesca Tovena, the theorem I'm refering to is Lemma 5.6.5.

And this result is false if the manifold is not suppose to be paracompact.

isn't a T2, N2 and locally euclidean topological space always paracompact?
